# ag-grid - getColumnState not working inside ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to save the ag-grid column state and re-apply when the user revisits the page. For this, I'm using ag-grid's  **columnApi** and **getColumnState** and **applyColumnState** methods;

This is working fine in normal cases. But when I'm trying to **getColumnState** on ngOnDestroy it always returns an empty array.

Can't we use the getColumnmState API inside the **ngOnDestrory** event?

EDIT - THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE WITH AG-GRID YET. Got reply from ag-grid team - https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/6983

Comment: Can confirm.
I had this problem 5-ish years ago, don't remember whether I filed an issue or not.
Anyway, I solved it by keeping track of the grid's state myself, any time that I changed it.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the same. Keeping the state as changed and saving at On Destroy event